# regex - optional and needed

Tags: regex, wildcard

I was trying some things with regex'es and I was wondering how to do the following:
Accept:

```
http://google.com
https://google.com
http://google.com/
https://google.com/
http://google.com/*
https://google.com/*
http://*.google.com
https://*.google.com
http://*.google.com/
https://*.google.com/
http://*.google.com/*
https://*.google.com/*
```

The subdomain wildcard may only contain [a-z][A-Z][0-9] and is optional, but if it exists a dot after it is required.

I came as far as:

```
https?://(www.)google.com/
```

But I think this is not the right way to work... and only www. is usable.
I hope someone could give me the required result, and explains why it works that way.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be what you're after:

```
https?://([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?google\.com(/.*)?
```

[this site](http://regexpal.com/) will help you validate your regular expressions. This seems to match what you want, but you may want to be more specific about the last part, as `.*` matches literally anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
http(s)?://([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?google\.com(/.*)?
```

[This is rmhartog answer, and it looks correct to me]
I just want to expand upon the why - which is asked in the question. OP please don't accept my answer, as I am just expanding upon the answer of the previous person.

```
http - This must be an exact match
(s)? - ? is zero or one time
://  - This must be an exact match
(    - start of a group
[a-zA-Z0-9] - Defines a character class that allows any of these characters in it.
+    - one or more of these characters must be present, empty set is invalid.
\.   - escapes the dot character (usually . is a wildcard in regex)
)?   - end of the group and the group can appear 0 or one time
google - This must be an exact match
\.   - escapes the dot character (usually . is a wildcard in regex)
com  - This must be an exact match
(    - start of a group
/    - This must be an exact match
.*   - matches any character 0 or more times (this fits anything you can type)
)?   - end of the group and the group can appear 0 or one time
```

I hope this helps explain the answer above, it would have been hard to fit this all in as a comment.

Comment: I agree, I should have elaborated on the *why*, thanks for doing that! Upped.

Answer (score 0):

As a POSIX ERE:

```
https?://(\*|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.)?google.com
```

The `(\*|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.)` portion indicates that you have either a `*` or an alphanumeric string, which is then followed by a dot. This is optional, so followed by a question mark.

You can also replace the ranges `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with a POSIX character class: `[[:alnum:]]`, giving:

```
https?://(\*|([[:alnum:]]+)\.)?google.com
```